# CMake find_package Boost fails on multiple usage

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to use a library that I wrote (is-msgs) that depends on boost::filesystem and have the following is-msgsConfig.cmake file:

```
include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

find_dependency(Protobuf)
find_dependency(spdlog)
find_dependency(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem)

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/is-msgsTargets.cmake")
```

If I try to use the library to build an executable, for instance, everything works like expected:

```
find_package(is-msgs)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example is-msgs::is-msgs)
```

Although if my executable also depends on another boost component, for instance, boost::chrono the following code will not work:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS chrono)
find_package(is-msgs)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example is-msgs::is-msgs boost::chrono)
```

Outputs:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable):
  Target "main" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

However, if I reorder the find_package instructions it works without a problem:

```
find_package(is-msgs)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS chrono)

add_executable(example example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example is-msgs::is-msgs boost::chrono)
```

Is something wrong with my is-msgsConfig.cmake file or is this a bug in find_package(Boost) ? I am using CMake 3.11.1.

Comment: As far as I know, repeating `find_package()` for the same component should work. So it looks like a bug in `find_dependency`, not in `find_package` itself.